# Python if with many or in a contracted form

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

I'm learning python and I found myself lost trying to create a an if statement that should be true if the user input y or yes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

user_input = input('Would you like to go on?')
lowui = user_input.lower

if lowui == ('y' or 'yes'):
   print('You want to go on')
else
   print('See you later, bye')
```

The problem is that it becomes true only if I type y but not for yes. If I remove the parenthesis it becomes always false. Ok, I can do a workaround like

```
if lowui == 'y' or lowui == 'yes':
```

but I was wondering if there is any trick that don't force me to write so many times tha variable.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change it to

```
if lowui in ('y', 'yes'):
```

Also this is wrong:

```
lowui = user_input.lower
```

it should be:

```
lowui = user_input.lower() # Actually call the lower function
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know about this kind of notation. Is it used just in python or is it used also in other languages?

Comment: @fcole90 I'm sure many other high level languages support it. It's not much of a notation, it just constructs a tuple and checks if the word is contained in it.