# While-Loop Troubles

Tags: python, while-loop

I have to make a gradebook program for my CS class, and I'm having problems with my while-loop (bear with me, I'm a beginner). I am trying to set it up so that a teacher will be able to add an infinite amount of students to their gradebook. We're also saving it to a text file. For some reason after I enter one name, the loop doesn't continue, it just skips to the other if statement below it. Thanks for your help.

```
#input students

studentnames=open("studentnames.txt","w")
stu = input ("Would you like to input new students? (Yes or No) ")
if stu == 'Yes' or 'yes':
    while True: 
        add = input ("Please enter the names you would like to add to your registry. (Type stop when you're finished.) ")
        studentnames.writelines(add)

        if add == 'Stop' or 'stop':
            break

if stu == 'No' or 'no':
    print ("Okay.")


studentnames.close()
```

Comment: try `if add.lower().strip() == 'stop'`

Comment: `add == 'Stop' or 'stop'` isn't the same as `add == 'Stop' or add == 'stop'`, the latter is what  you really want.

Comment: All of the OR conditions are wrong syntax.

Comment: the same goes for the stu == 'Yes' or 'yes', you want it to be stu == 'Yes' or stu == 'yes'

Comment: 'stop' is always evaluated as True.

Comment: Please improve your title. _"While-Loop Troubles"_ could mean _anything_.

Comment: The two statements in the `or` are completely separate. You can't think the same way about them as you would if you said them in English. `if stu == 'Yes':` does what you expect, but `"yes"` will always evaluate to `True`. The result is that because it's an `or` and the second statement is always `True` is that the result will always be `True`. The easiest way to do the comparison is to convert the input to upper or lower case and compare to a version that is in that case. e.g. `if stu.lower() == 'yes'`. Your `while` loop is fine your `if`'s are iffy.

Comment: ...```If add in ['Stop', 'stop']:``` or ```if add.lower() == 'stop'``` - my .02, couldn't help myself.

Comment: There have to be a million previous questions that this could be closed as a duplicate of. Someone please find one.

Comment: [Using OR in Python for a yes/no?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16544393/using-or-in-python-for-a-yes-no)

Comment: Or [Python if with many or in a contracted form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681028/python-if-with-many-or-in-a-contracted-form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. The problem is that python understands line

```
if add == 'Stop' or 'stop':
```

as

```
if (add == 'Stop') or ('stop'):
```

So. Even if `add == 'Stop'` is False, python casts `'stop'` to True, so it executes if statement anyway.
So use `if add.lower() == 'stop':` instead. (same in `if stu == 'No' or 'no':`)

Comment: And, I think, you should check `if  add.lower() == 'stop':` before writing to file. Because it will write 'stop' to file at the end.